# ModX Ressources tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I am using MODX Revolution 2.2.1-pl (advanced) and I've got a problem. My resource tree is... uhm... away... not shown... invisible.

When I log in to the Manager, my JS console says:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
(<>br />
ext-all.js (Zeile 7, Spalte 1)
```

(beware ... the '>' in the **br** line is only for displaying the error message and not a part of the error itself.

I've never touched this (ext-all.js) file which is compressed and it is very confusing that I get this error.

Does anybody, who had to deal with the same problem before, have a solution for me? I'm afraid that this problem will get even worse if I update MODX.

thanks,

ShaoKhan

Comment: so, i've changed the css and / or js compression to yes and / or no. No way to get my ressource tree back :(

Answer (score 0):

Purge your cache first, then;

Turn off script & css compression & caching in the modx system settings. I think this was fixed in 2.2.2+

This was a fairly common thing, but I'm nt sure what the exact error was ~ so am not sure if this is what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this, but I've had some problems with compressed javascript in the manager. If your settings-page works, try disabeling this.

Set:

> compress_js to No

Comment: i've just updated the whole thing. all fine now. thanks for reply's.